# How to play many audio files with one html5 audio player

Tags: javascript, php, html, audio

We are trying to make a html5 audio player in which we have more than one `.mp3 file` which we shows in tabular form using `loop with php` and we actually want that : when we will click on every `mp3 file` then it should be play in only one interface just like as http://gaana.com.

What we did :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['song'])) {
    $song_name = $_GET['song'];
    echo "<audio id=\"audio1\" src=\"$song_name.mp3\" controls preload=\"none\" type=\"audio/mp3\" autobuffer autoplay></audio>";   
}

?>

<script>
function EvalSound(soundobj) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.play();
}
function EvalSound1(soundobj1) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj1);
  thissound.pause();
}
</script>
```

in the above code we are getting the `.mp3 file` using `get` method and we are passing the `mp3 file` name in within url.

Answer (score 0):

DEMONSTRATION CODE:

```js
var tracks = ['https://archive.org/download/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3', 'http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3'];

Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("button"), function(element, index){
    element.addEventListener("click", changeTrack.bind(null, tracks[index]), false);  
});

var autoPlay = true;
function changeTrack(track)
{
   var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio1");
   audioElement.src = track;
}
audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", startPlaying, false);

function startPlaying()
{
    if (autoPlay)
    {
        this.play();
    }
}
```

```html
<button>Track 1</button>
<button>Track 2</button>

<audio id="audio1" src="song_name.mp3" controls preload="none" type="audio/mp3" autobuffer autoplay></audio>";
```

CORE CODE (actual solution)

```
var autoPlay = true;
function changeTrack(track)
{
   var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio1");
   audioElement.src = track;
}
audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", startPlaying, false);

function startPlaying()
{
    if (autoPlay)
    {
        this.play();
    }
}
```

When somebody clicks on another audio link, it should invoke the function `changeTrack()` with an argument referring to the track's url. If the track is loaded it will start to play.

Comment: How do you mean full code. This is what you asked. You need to implement this by yourself. This site helps coders solve there coding problems, it's not a code request site.